# searchresult usin sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

i am using sphinx beta and thinking-sphinx to perform search functionality..the search i

```
wann should search for the word i entered in the database.which is populated with data already.
so in my application Mydoc,i got articlesmodel and controller.. articles is db is populated with data.

i wann to search for the data in articles..so far i ve done with following things but not getting the search result

=> created new search controller
  def index
   @articles = Article.search params[:search]
   end


 => articles.rb(model)
    define_index do

  indexes name, :sortable => true
    indexes description
    indexes title, :sortable => true
    end
 def self.search(search)
  ThinkingSphinx::Search
 end
 => searches/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag  do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
  BUT WEN I CLICK ON THE SEARCH BUTTON ITS ASKING FOR CREATEACTION ?????
PLEASE COULD U HELP TO GET SEARCH RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is making a POST request to your SearchController, and that is interpreted as a call to the create action. Try using a GET request instead with your form - something like this:

```
<%= form_tag '', :method => :get do %>
```